# How to set a margin position for primeNG overlay pannel?

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-dialog

I want to set margin-top and margin-left position for primeNG overlay panel dynamically. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve that with the tag **[style]** in your html:

```
<p-overlayPanel [style]="marginStyle">
</p-overlayPanel>
```

and declaring the margin that you want in the .ts like this:

```
positionLeft = '90px'; 
positionTop = '20px';
marginStyle = { 'margin-left': this.positionLeft , 'margin-top': this.positionTop };
```

You can check the live example here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-overlay-position-style

Comment: This answer helped me to set style for overlayPanel